# A high probability bound for a Rademacher process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics

Let $\{x_i(t)\}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. Gaussian processes for $t \in [0, T]$ with
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[x_i(t)] & = 0, \quad \forall i \in [1 : n], \ t \in [0, T] \\
\mathbb{E}[x_i(s) x_i(t)] & = K(s,t), \quad \forall i \in [1 : n], \ s, t \in [0, T]
\end{align*}
where $K(t,t)=1$ for $t \in [0, T]$.

I want to know how to get a high probability bound for the Rademacher process
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\sigma} \left[\sup_{t \in [0, T]} \left|\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i x_i(t)\right|\right]
$$
where $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_i=1) = \mathbb{P}(\sigma_i=-1) =0.5$.

I try to tackle this problem from the case when $T = 0$, then the Gaussian processes are reduced to i.i.d. standard normal random variables $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$.
Then we have
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\sigma} \left|\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i x_i\right| \leq 
\sqrt{\mathbb{E}_{\sigma} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i x_i\right)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i}
$$
where the term $\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i$ is a Chi-squared random variable and we can have a high probability bound by some concentration inequalities.

But I do not have an idea for the case when $T > 0$.
Any help is appreciated.